# Jquery how to add onclick in href

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

how to add `onclick='openLightB('remove_ddi',500);'` in to `<a>open</a>` with jquery function

my present code is like this

```
$(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
  $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").replaceWith("<a onclick='openLightB('remove_ddi',500);'>Remove</a>");
});
```

unfortunately result coming like this

```
<a remove_ddi',500);'="" onclick="openLightB(">Remove</a>
```

Comment: the .live() function is deprecated and you should be using .delegate() or .on() depending on what version of jQuery you're using.

Comment: and `return openLight...` with openlight returning false. Or use jQuery to assigh the click too

Comment: even delegate is deprecated...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about letting jquery deal with escaping the quotes by using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
  $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").attr('onclick', "openLightB('remove_ddi',500);");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/LTmfc/)

---

BTW, [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is **deprecated** and could be removed from the library any time in the future. You should consider using [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for event delegation.

Answer (score 5):

You can fix your code by changing it as below,

```
$(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
  $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a")
     .replaceWith("<a onclick=\'openLightB(\'remove_ddi\',500);\'>Remove</a>");
});
```

or simplify it,

```
 $(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
    $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").click (function () {
      $(this).text('Remove');
      openLightB('remove_ddi',500);
     });
 });
```

Also if you are using jQuery 1.7, then use `.on`

```
//replace <.remove_row container> with .remove_row container
 $('<.remove_row container>').on("click", '.remove_row', function(){
    $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").click (function () {
      $(this).text('Remove');
      openLightB('remove_ddi',500);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

This work for quotes problems:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".remove_row").click( function(){
          $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").replaceWith("<a onclick=\"openLightB('remove_ddi',500);\">Remove</a>");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
  $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").attr('onclick', 'openLightB("remove_ddi",500);');
});
```

Comment: I don't believe you can set a click event with .attr() - you would need to use .click() instead.

Comment: @SurrealDreams. It's just an attribute, not a binding in terms of jquery.

Comment: That's correct.  The onclick event won't actually work because it's not bound.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<a href="javascript:openLightB('remove_ddi',500)">Remove</a>
```

jquery

```
$(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
  $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").prop('href','javascript:openLightB("remove_ddi",500);');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".remove_row").live("click", function(){
 $(".ddi tr:eq(2) td:eq(5) a").attr('onClick', 'openLightB("remove_ddi",500);'); });
```